# Django. Передача переменной в форму

Tags: python, django

Просьба подсказать как передать результат функции "AD_search" в форму после ее обработки во "views"? В сам код функции можно не вникать, тут нужен именно конечный результат.

```
def AD_search(user=''):
    server = Server('10.0.0.90', get_info=ALL)
    conn = Connection(server,'K.Inkin@in.trkua.net','Kk*9876543210!', auto_bind=True)
    filter = '(&(objectClass=user)(sn={}*))'.format(user)
    attrs = ['sAMAccountName']



conn.search('DC=in,DC=trkua,DC=net',filter, attributes=attrs)
entry=conn.entries

users_list = []
for i in entry:
    users = str(i.sAMAccountName)
    users_tuple = (users, users)
    users_list.append(users_tuple)

   # print(i)
users_list= sorted(users_list, key=itemgetter(1))
return users_list
```

views.py:

```
def test(request):
    form = TestForm
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if 'btn_search' in request.GET:
            user = request.GET.get('search_field')
            return render(request, 'Test.html', {'form': form, 'user':user})
```

forms.py:

```
class TestForm(forms.Form):
    search_field = forms.CharField(max_length=50, label='Фамилия пользователя в AD')
    choise = forms.ChoiceField(choices=AD_search())


form = TestForm
return render(request, 'Test.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: Вызовите функцию из представления, получите результат (`AD_search_result`) и добавьте его в контекст: `return render(request, 'Test.html', {'form': form, 'user':user, 'AD_search_result': AD_search_result})`. И ещё совет — не переопределяйте `user`, в шаблон автоматически подгружается текущий.

Comment: Используйте [initial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values).

Comment: `AD_search` должна вернуть словарь кортежей (либо Enum). И `choices=AD_search` без скобок. Вроде так должно работать, но при условии, что она будет вызвана один раз при инициализации модели

Comment: В этом и сложность. Мне нужно сначала через форму поиска достать список пользователей AD. А затем в другой колонке формы из этого списка я должен выбрать один из вариантов. И вот непонятно как передать результат функции AD_search в колонку формы choise, чтоб получить варианты выбора.

Comment: @KirillInkin, тогда см первые два комментария к вопросу